No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Deployment
This erro i get when i deploy https://github.com/Juan-Vera-ok/Memory-game-fullstack
This is the error i recieve from the client browser, i already tried everything i found in the CORS documentation

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://memory-game-fullstack.onrender.com/highScore-current-user' from origin 'https://memory-game-client.onrender.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


This is code from my server:

app.use(cors({
  origin: "https://memory-game-client.onrender.com",
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type",
  "Authorization",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"],
  methods: ["GET","HEAD","PUT","PATCH","POST","DELETE","OPTIONS"],
  preflightContinue:true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 204
}));

This is code from my client:
const checkPattern = async (userPattern: number[]) => {
        let lost = false
        for (let i = 0; i < userPattern.length; i++) {
            if (pattern[i] != userPattern[i]) {
                lost = true
                break;
            }
        }


        if (lost) {
            setisPlaying(false)
            setPattern([]);
            setUserPattern([]);
        } else {
            if (pattern.length === userPattern.length) {

                const newPattern = generateRandomNumber();
                await setTimeout(() => { showPattern(newPattern) }, 1000)

                setPattern(newPattern)
                setUserPattern([]);
                if (userPattern.length > userHighScore) {
                    const newUserHighScore = userHighScore + 1;
                    setUserHighScore(newUserHighScore)
                    const response = axios.post(`${BACKEND_URL}/update-highscore`, { newUserHighScore }, 
                    { 
                        withCredentials:true,
                         })


                }

            }
        }

    };

This is the code from the server, the route /update-highscore
export const updateHighScore: RequestHandler = async (req, res) => {
console.log(req.cookies.token)
    const tokenPromise = verifyToken(req.cookies.token)
    tokenPromise.then(async (_id) => {
        const user = await User.findById(_id);
        
        if (!user) { throw new Error }
        if (!user.highScore||user.highScore < req.body.newUserHighScore) {
            await User.updateOne({ _id: user._id }, { $set: { 'highScore': req.body.newUserHighScore } })
            return res.json(user)
        }
    })


}

Sorry for my bad english, it's not my language
I tried to update the highScore of current user on the database sending a POST petition with axios from the client and does'n work. This is the error i get:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://memory-game-fullstack.onrender.com/highScore-current-user' from origin 'https://memory-game-client.onrender.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

